# Socket recebendo mais de uma mensagem junto

Tags: c#

Tenho um socket client recebendo mensagens em xml que está funcionando normalmente porém em alguns momentos é necessário que o servidor me envie mais de uma mensagem referente a uma solicitação, e essas mensagens são enviadas num intervalo de tempo muito pequeno algo como centésimos e então essas mensagens chegam todas juntas o que dificulta a interpretação do client. É possível que o socket consiga receber essas mensagens separadas ? Meu socket é assíncrono.

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
                    // from the asynchronous state object.
                    StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                    Socket client = state.workSocket;

                    // Read data from the remote device.
                    int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

                    if (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                        //state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                        String received = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        if (received == keepAliveMsg)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] - " + "Keep Alive received.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sendToXMLController(received);
                            //Console.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "] - " + received + "\n");
                        }



                            // Get the rest of the data.
                            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);     


                    }                   

                    else {
                        // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                        if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                        {
                            response = state.sb.ToString();
                        }
                        // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                        receiveDone.Set();
                    }



                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não, não tem como fazer ele receber as mensagens separadamente.

Para ser mais correto, não existe separação de mensagens, ou melhor ainda, não existem "mensagens". Estas "mensagens" são uma abstração que se cria em seu programa para funcionar em cima da comunicação pelos Sockets.

A garantia que se tem quando se usa TCP/IP é de que os dados vão chegar e que eles vão chegar na mesma ordem em que foram enviados (só por comparação, UDP não garante nada disto). O que ele não garante é que vá chegar separado os dados se foram feitos envios consecutivos, neste caso eles podem chegar juntos, e também de que vá chegar tudo de uma vez só, pois um outro problema que você não teve mas pode vir a ter se os dados forem grandes é de chegar apenas parte da informação, e logo em seguida chegar separado o resto.

A comunicação deveria funcionar em um loop mais ou menos da seguinte forma

1. Espera chegar (mais) dados
2. Recebe os dados e adicionar eles no final de um buffer de dados recebidos
3. Verifica se já tem dados suficientes para tratar no buffer

   - Se já tem dados suficientes, remove os dados do começo do buffer e trata eles da forma necessária, em seguida volta para (3), pois pode ser que tenha chegado mais de uma mensagem inteira junto
   - Se não tem dados suficientes volta para o (1)

Um detalhe é de que o buffer que eu me refiro não é o `state.buffer` de seu código, este é o buffer que recebe os bytes da comunicação, o que você precisa é de um outro buffer para ir guardando todos os dados que chegam.

No seu código da para ver que provavelmente no exemplo que você usou eles faziam isso, isso é visto pela linha comentada.

```
// There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
//state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
```

Então você deveria pegar o que chegou no `state.buffer` e primeiro de tudo adicionar no final de outro buffer, como estava sendo feito com o `state.sb`, só depois disso é que você deve conferir se já chegaram todos os dados.

E para saber se já chegaram todos os dados é outra coisa que você vai precisar definir em seu programa, criando um protocolo de comunicação própria.

Ele pode ser bem simples, por exemplo se você envia apenas textos você pode prefixar a mensagem com o tamanho dela, para ficar mais fácil pode ser feito com o valor em hexadecimal sempre com 8 dígitos, no estilo

```
0000002C<meuxml><dados>Teste<dados></meuxml>
```

Assim eu posso ler os primeiros 8 caracteres e saber que esta mensagem tem 44 caracteres, sendo que 8 deles são do prefixo contendo o tamanho, então o loop seria do tipo

1. Espera chegar (mais) dados
2. Recebe os dados e adicionar eles no final de um buffer de dados recebidos
3. Verifica se já tem mais de 8 caracteres no buffer

   - Se tem mais de 8 caracteres você apenas lê estes 8 caracteres (sem remover do buffer) para descobrir o tamanho da mensagem, caso contrário retorna ao (1)
   - Sabendo o tamanho da mensagem então você verifica se já recebeu uma quantidade igual ou maior de caracteres, se sim, só então você remove estes dados do começo do buffer, remove o prefixo dele e trata eles da forma necessária, em seguida volta para (3), pois pode ser que tenha chegado mais de uma mensagem inteira junto, caso contrário volta para o (1)

E esta é apenas uma forma bem simples de se fazer um protocolo de texto, seria possível também usar delimitadores, mas dai teria que garantir que os delimitadores nunca iriam aparecer no texto, e você teria que ficar procurando no meio do texto estes delimitadores, por isso acho o uso de um prefixo com o tamanho mais simples e prático, pois só se precisa ler alguns caracteres no começo.